# Fastest way to render a tiled map with SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm searching for a very fast way to render a tiled map with three layers with SDL2.
I'm using SDL_RenderCopy but it's very slow...

Comment: Are you rendering whole map (even tiles that are outside of the screen) or are you performing some kind of view culling? Also use `SDL_GetRendererInfo` to see if you are getting hardware acceleration and try turning off alpha blending for textures that don't need it. If none of that helps and rendering speed is really the reason of slowness here then I guess what you are trying to do is too much for simple SDL rendering and you could switch to something more advanced and faster (if used right) like OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already checked it all, and I've now found the solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, I've found what I needed, so I'll explain it here.

I've actually four layers, and I used to render them in a simple for loop.
In fact, the for loop isn't a good way to render tiled maps.

The best way is to render each layer into a big texture, before the main rendering loop, and then render each big texture to screen. The for loop takes a lot of time to process, however, rendering a big texture is very fast.

Take a look at the following code, considering that "bigTexture" is a layer, and "width" and "height" the size of that layer.

```
Uint32 pixelFormat;
SDL_QueryTexture(tileset, &pixelFormat, NULL, NULL, NULL);
SDL_Texture *bigTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, pixelFormat, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, width, height);
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, bigTexture);
// Put your for loop here
```

It's done, we loaded our layer into a big texture. Let's see how to render it.

```
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
// Create a SDL_Rect which defines the big texture's part to display, ie the big texture's part visible in the window.
// Display the big texture with a simple SDL_RenderCopy
```

That's all. You're now able to render tiled maps in a very fast way.