# Drawing tiles with SDL_RenderFillRect() causes strange flickering/graphical bugs

Tags: c, sdl-2

In my game, there is a map (2D array) represented by tiles some of which are walls and each on of them I draw with SDL_RenderFillRect(), but for some reason when moving the camera (the position of each rect is determined by camera offset) I get light lines appearing on the screen (like seams between the tiles maybe) and something like tearing. I don't understand where this would come from, because I first render everything and SDL_RenderPresent() it once. These bugs are most noticeable on Android, perhaps because of the CPU/GPU being slower or something. I did try to enable Vsync/cap FPS, but that didn't help much.

Here is a piece of code where I draw the tiles (the entire source code can be found [here](https://github.com/postmodernist1488/Cants)):

```c
//only iterate over walls that are on the screen
for (int i = g_camera.y / CELL_SIZE; i < (g_camera.y + g_camera.h + CELL_SIZE) / CELL_SIZE && i < g_map.height; i++) {
    for (int j = g_camera.x / CELL_SIZE; j < (g_camera.x + g_camera.w + CELL_SIZE) / CELL_SIZE && j < g_map.width; j++) {
        if (g_map.matrix[i][j] == MAP_WALL) {
            SDL_Rect coords = {
                j * CELL_SIZE - g_camera.x,
                i * CELL_SIZE - g_camera.y,
                CELL_SIZE,
                CELL_SIZE
            };
            SDL_RenderFillRect(g_renderer, &coords);
        }
        else if (g_map.matrix[i][j] == MAP_FOOD) {
            render_texture(g_leaf_texture, j * CELL_SIZE - g_camera.x, i * CELL_SIZE - g_camera.y);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the result looks like, though it's very hard to capture the graphical bugs:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Confused. Does presented screenshot show the problem or not? If you have literally tearing (e.g. upper part of the screen showing one frame but lower showing previous one) then vsync is the correct answer, limitiing FPS is not. How do you set vsync? Could you check return value of `SDL_RenderSetVSync`?

Comment: I've checked your full code. In my observation, what happens is your tile rendering actually puts some tiles as if camera was in previous position and some after it was moved, because your player position gets updated in background thread while you're rendering, and you re-read camera position on each loop iteration within the same frame. You can solve this by caching camera position to local variable before starting rendering, or by updating game logic before rendering, not during.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I just moved one line of code (setting the camera coordinates to those of the player) from one thread to where the actual drawing happens and there is no more glitches. This is my first time using multithreading, so I didn't know where the problem was coming from and didn't provide this information in the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

User [keltar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744720/keltar) has provided the answer in the comments.
I set g_camera.x and g_camera.y in the callback function that runs in another thread, so its position was changing parallel to drawing the map. What I did is change the camera position in the function that draws the map instead (the main thread)

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from an SDL2 expert, but I think you shouldn't draw it tile by tile. Because this means every tick of the program, SDL2 is drawing your whole map tile by tile which is a lot of function calls.

I think you want to draw to a preliminary texture. See the answer here : [Fastest way to render a tiled map with SDL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132531/fastest-way-to-render-a-tiled-map-with-sdl2)